# How to find two square roots whose difference is greater than one.

Tags: contest-math, roots, square-numbers

How do you find the greatest $n$ such that the difference of its square root from some other integer is greater than or equal to one? For example : $$2011^{1/2} - n^{1/2} \ge1$$

What should be the greatest integer value of $n$ such that the difference is more than one? Is there a specific method to find this?

Comment: You may want the *greatest* $n$ such that $2011^{1/2}-n^{1/2}$ is greater than $1$. The *least* value is $0$.

Comment: yep!! that's the case..the greatest one@AndréNicolas

Comment: I'm sure you've figured out that you have to find $n$ such that $n^{\frac12} <= \sqrt{2011} - 1$.  Another way to do this mentally is to find approx sqrt of $2011$ which is $44...$. Subtract around $2*44.. + 1$ from $2011$ and you will have your answer which is $\color{blue}{1922}$. This this was specified as contest, I just thought of writing how I would do it in a contest... the mathematics behind it can be reasoned out.

Comment: thnanxxx!! it'sjust the same method right..@Shailesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{2011} - \sqrt{n} & \geq 1 \\
  \sqrt{n} & \leq \sqrt{2011} - 1 \\
  n & \leq (\sqrt{2011} - 1)^{2} \\
    &= 2011+1-2\sqrt{2011} \\
    &= 1922.31165 \ldots \\
\end{align*}

The greatest value of $n$ is $1922$.